# labels read as [object Object] and doesn't get the value Livewire with Chart.js

Tags: chart.js, laravel-livewire

Hello I really need help the labels doesn't display from the chart and the value I'm using Laravel Livewire and Chart Js  the labels shows 4 [object Object] which 4 items and correct but doesn't display the name

what I'm trying to do is get the course name as labels and the getRandomnumber is the number of values from that table

here is my code
Livewire View

```
<div>
<div class="justify-content-end text-end" style="right:0;">
    <select   style="width: 9rem;">
      
         <option value="{{ date('Y')}}">{{ date('Y')}}</option> 
             
    </select>
    
</div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
@once
    @push('scripts')
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    @endpush
@endonce

@push('scripts')
    <script>
        const chart = new Chart(
            document.getElementById('myChart'), {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: @json($labels),
                    datasets: @json($dataset)
                },
                        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
            }
        });
        Livewire.on('updateChart', data => {
            chart.data = data;
            chart.update();
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

This is the Livewire Component

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Chart;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Enrollment;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class ChartEnrollmentFirstYr extends Component
{


    public array $dataset = [];
    public array $labels = [];
    public function mount()
    {
        $this->labels[] = $this->getLabels();

        $this->dataset = [
            [
                'label' => 'Enrollees',
                'backgroundColor' => '#1d7e43',
               
                'data' => $this->getRandomData(),
            ],
        ];
        $labels = $this->getLabels();

        $dataset = [
            [
                'label' => 'Enrolless',
                'backgroundColor' => '#1d7e43',
               
                'data' => $this->getRandomData(),
            ],
        ];
        $this->emit('updateChart', [
            'datasets' => $dataset,
            'labels' => $labels,
        ]);
    
    }
    
    private function getLabels()
    {
        $labels = [];

        $alumni = DB::table('enrollments')         
        ->join('academic_programs', 'academic_programs.id','=','enrollments.degree_id')
        ->select('academic_programs.program_abbv as course, DB::raw(count(enrollments.id) as total)') 
        ->groupBy('academic_programs.program_abbv')
        ->orderBy('course')
        ->get();
        foreach ($alumni as $alu)
       {
        $labels[]= $alu;
       }
        return $labels;
    }

    private function getRandomData()
    {
        $data = [];
        $alumni = Enrollment::where('degree_id','!=',NULL)->orderBy('degree_id', 'ASC')->get();
        foreach ($alumni as $alu => $values )
       {
        $data[]= $values;
       }
        return $data;
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.chart.chart-enrollment-first-yr');
    }
  
 

}
```

Comment: It seems you are feeding objects to `labels`, there should be strings only; I don't know the structure of you database, but you have to select one component for each alumnus. I'll use `name` as an example, but you have to replace `name` with the real property in the db. You can do it in PHP by modifying the `getLabels` function, in the `foreach`: `$labels[] = $alu->name` or in the javascript `labels: (@json($labels)).map(o=>o.name),`

Comment: hello thank you so much the javascript is working now the only problem is the count data is not align in the labels but the numbers are correct

Comment: hello i have already figure out that javascript really help me a lot I've been working this for about 1-2 weeks and here I thought it will never work I can finally have my hopes passing this subject from school thank you